# SQL: Return values if data shows up over window of time

Tags: sql, presto

I have a script that runs daily to check the status of orders for different sellers. The output populates a table that looks like this, which tells me the failure status of an order:

```
| date       | failure                 | order | seller_id |
|------------|-------------------------|-------|-----------|
| 2021-04-01 | stuck_in_pending_status | 123   | user1     |
| 2021-04-01 | shipping_is_late        | 456   | user2     |
| 2021-04-01 | stuck_in_pending_status | 789   | user3     |
| 2021-04-02 | stuck_in_pending_status | 123   | user1     |
| 2021-04-02 | shipping_is_late        | 456   | user2     |
| 2021-04-03 | stuck_in_pending_status | 123   | user1     |
| 2021-04-04 | stuck_in_pending_status | 987   | user1     |
| 2021-04-04 | shipping_is_late        | 654   | user3     |
```

I can get summary stats on the overall health of the system with this query to see how orders are failing and if orders are piling up/there is a spike in failures for any particular date
:

```
SELECT
    date,
    failure,
    COUNT(0)
FROM my table
WHERE
    date >= '2021-03-01'
GROUP BY
    date,
    failure
```

I can also add `seller_id = foo` to the `WHERE` clause to get seller specific failures

I would like to get a bit more granular and see the specific health of orders at the seller level, specifically if there are issues with the same order over a period of time (say 3 days). So if the same order shows up in the failures over a 3 day period give me the seller so that I can notify someone to look into why that is happening.

For example, with the table above, I would like the query to return `user1` since order `123` has had an issue for 3 straight days.
What would be the best way to structure a query like that? Would I use a `WINDOW` function?

Comment: Please define "failure".  Nothing in the data seems to represent this.

Comment: The column is named 'failure', so if the order shows up in the table 3 days in a row (regardless of the failure i.e. for days 1 and 2 it is stuck in pending, and day 3 it is shipped late), then return the seller_id and the order.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly , you can use window function:

```
select * from (
SELECT * , 
    row_number() over (partition by order, seller_id order by date desc) rn
FROM mytable
WHERE date >= '2021-03-01'
) t 
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `lag()`.  To get all rows that are the "third" in order, you can use:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, 
             lag(date, 2) over (partition by order_id order by date) as date_2
      from mytable t
     ) t
where date_2 = date - interval '2 day';
```

Note:  data/time functions are specific to a database.  This uses standard syntax; you may need to tweak for your database.